# Try to make fine-tuning of model gpt like

Tags: python, nlp, kaggle

I try to make fine tuning on essays, my datset looks like:

```
[ {
        "topic": "Мы были достаточно цивилизованны, чтобы построить машину, но слишком примитивны, чтобы ею пользоваться». (Карл Краус)",
        "text": "Высказывание Карла Крауса, австрийского писателя, о том, что «мы были достаточно цивилизованны, чтобы построить машину... }]
```

There is the code:

```
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelWithLMHead, Trainer, TrainingArguments
model_name = "tinkoff-ai/ruDialoGPT-medium"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelWithLMHead.from_pretrained(model_name)
import json

def prepare_data(filepath):
    with open(filepath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    prompts = [example["topic"] for example in data]
    texts = [example["text"] for example in data]
    inputs = []
    for i in range(len(prompts)):
        inputs.append(prompts[i] + texts[i])
    return inputs
    
train_inputs = prepare_data("train.json")
test_inputs = prepare_data("test.json")
from transformers import TextDataset, DataCollatorForLanguageModeling

train_dataset = TextDataset(tokenizer=tokenizer, file_path="train.json", block_size=128)
test_dataset = TextDataset(tokenizer=tokenizer, file_path="test.json", block_size=128)

data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(
    tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm=False,
)
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./models",
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=8,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=8,
    num_train_epochs=2,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    push_to_hub=False,
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=test_dataset,
    data_collator=data_collator,
)

trainer.train()
```

But it takes a lot of memory, and i can't fin-tune it in Kaggle. The output has >19gb.
Is it normal or how can i fix it?
[2501/7802 59:11 < 26:52, 2.06 it/s, Epoch 0.86/3] every 10 minutes it takes 2-3 GB, is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
   gradient_accumulation_steps=2,
```

Comment: It doesn't help. In  [ 1087/17478 05:42 < 1:26:21, 3.16 it/s, Epoch 0.19/3] i already have 8,2 gb in kaggle memory...

Comment: I just edit my answer, let’s try this approach. Use gradient accumulation by accumulating gradients for several steps before updating the model

Comment: doesn't help, the same problem(

Comment: my every 500 step gives 4gb(

Comment: how can i find the mistake in algoritm?

Comment: If memory consumption is still an issue, you can try using a smaller version of the model to reduce memory usage or you can try this     fp16=True,

Comment: I find that my fine tuning has been making a checkpoints in a different steps like 500, 1000, may be it's the problem? 1 checkpoint includes config.json, generation_config, optimizer.ptm pytorch_model.bin, rng_state.pth, scheduler.pt, trainer_state.json, training_args,bin